# Angular 2 GET withCredentials (to accept cookies from server)

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

I can see that `withCredentials: true` [**is implemented in angular 2 now**](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptionsArgs-interface.html)

To accept cookies from server.

However I am not sure how I supposed to use it.

I tried

```
this.http.get( API_PATH + 'auth/getSession/' + TOKEN, {
  withCredentials: true
} )
```

But Broccoli throws error

`Argument of type '{ withCredentials: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'`

I use 1.0.0-beta.6 of Angular CLI.

Comment: What version of Angular 2 are using in your `packages.json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`withCredentials` is usable from the RC2 version of Angular2. Angular CLI 1.0.0-beta.6 uses the RC1 version.

You should upgrade to beta.8 to be able to use version RC2+.